# When do you precede non-static GameObject methods and properties with gameObject in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, naming-conventions, gameobject, non-static

For properties, `layer` needs `gameObject` to precede it but `transform` doesn't.

For methods, `SetActive()` needs `gameObject` to precede it but `GetComponent<T>()` doesn't.

Second question: is there a convention to use `gameObject.[method/property name]` at times instead of only writing `[method/property name]` (when appropriate)?

Comment: I, and people I've worked with, always do just to be as explicit as possible but I don't know what official convention is. I don't think it's mentioned in the unity style guide.